# Asterisks in front of array names in Groovy?

Tags: groovy

I'm a bit new to Groovy, so I'm sure this is one of those extremely obvious things...but it's difficult to search for via Google.

In other languages, asterisks tend to represent pointers. However, in this snippet of Groovy code:

```
byte[] combineArrays(foo, bar, int start) {
  [*foo[0..<start], *bar, *foo[start..<foo.size()]]
}
```

I can only imagine that that's not the case. I mean, pointers? Groovy?

I'm assuming that this code intends to pass the **members** of foo and bar as opposed to a multidimensional array. So what exactly do the asterisks mean?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Correct; it flattens the collection. Although there's no passing here, just flattens them into the new collection. But don't get sucked into thinking things in `"[]"` are arrays, because they're not.

Comment: (I shouldn't say flatten, since that's something different--it un-collections a collection turning it into individual elements. Asplodes it.

Comment: Mr Haki (as usual) [has the spread operator covered](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2009/09/groovy-goodness-spread-operator.html) with a few examples

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When used like this, the * operator spreads a List or Array into a list of arguments. That didn't help at all, did it? How about an example instead? Say we have this function:

```
def add(Number a, Number b) {
  return a + b
}
```

And this List

```
def args = [1, 2]
```

We shouldn't do this:

```
add(args)
```

because the function expects two numeric arguments. But we can do this:

```
add(*args)
```

because the * operator converts the List of 2 elements into 2 arguments. You can use this operator with Lists and Arrays.

Comment: Groovy will automatically spread the args, so your first example works too.

Comment: @taylor that's true, but it's a horrible feature of the language IMO, and is scheduled for removal in Groovy 2.0 (so it's use shouldn't be encouraged)